# Zero Fill Blanks in existing fields

Tags: ms-access-2013

Within an MSAccess query and not VBA, can I Zero fill unused spaces in a field?

Most of the fields have a total and must be 11 characters long. The field current views like, 4200 =$42.00, but I need it to look like 00000004200.

The following is what i tried, but it is left justifying and not zero filling.
WagesC: Format([WagesCC],"!" & String(11,"@"))

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Set the *Format* property of the field(s) where you display the values to: 00000000000